# In Perl, what is the difference between a .pm (Perl module) and .pl (Perl script) file?

Tags: perl, perl-module

What is the Difference between `.pm` (Perl module) and `.pl` (Perl script) file?

Please also tell me why we return `1` from file. If return 2 or anything else, it's not generating any error, so why do we return `1` from Perl module?

Comment: `1` does not matter. It can be `2`, it can be `"foo"`, it can be `["a", "list"]`. What matters is it's not `0`, or anything else that evaluates as false, or `use` would fail.

Comment: .pl is actually a perl library - perl scripts, like C programs or programs written in other languages, do not have an ending, except on operating systems that need one to functiopn, such as windows.

Comment: See [What is the difference between library files and modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6376006/589924)

Answer (score 87):

At the very core, the file extension you use makes no difference as to how `perl` interprets those files.

However, putting modules in `.pm` files following a certain directory structure that follows the package name provides a convenience. So, if you have a module `Example::Plot::FourD` and you put it in a directory `Example/Plot/FourD.pm` in a path in your [`@INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40INC), then [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) and [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) will do the right thing when given the package name as in `use Example::Plot::FourD`.

> The file must return true as the last statement to indicate successful execution of any initialization code, so it's customary to end such a file with `1;`  unless you're sure it'll return true otherwise. But it's better just to put the `1;`, in case you add more statements.
>
> If `EXPR` is a bareword, the `require` assumes a ".pm" extension and replaces "::" with "/" in the filename for you, to make it easy to load standard modules. This form of loading of modules does not risk altering your namespace.

All `use` does is to figure out the filename from the package name provided, `require` it in a `BEGIN` block and invoke `import` on the package. There is nothing preventing you from not using `use` but taking those steps manually.

For example, below I put the `Example::Plot::FourD` package in a file called `t.pl`, loaded it in a script in file `s.pl`.

```
C:\Temp> cat t.pl
package Example::Plot::FourD;

use strict; use warnings;

sub new { bless {} => shift }

sub something { print "something\n" }

"Example::Plot::FourD"

C:\Temp> cat s.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

BEGIN {
    require 't.pl';
}

my $p = Example::Plot::FourD->new;
$p->something;


C:\Temp> s
something
```

This example shows that module files do not have to end in `1`, any true value will do.

Answer (score -4):

A `.pl` is a single script.

In `.pm` ([Perl Module](https://theworld.com/%7Eswmcd/steven/perl/module_mechanics.html)) you have functions that you can use from other Perl scripts:

> A Perl module is a self-contained piece of Perl code that can be used by a Perl program or by other Perl modules. It is conceptually similar to a C link library, or a C++ class.

Comment: "A .pl is a single script." Not true. It's only on broken operating systems that you need to identify Perl programs with a .pl extension. And originally .pl indicated a "Perl library" - external subroutines that you loaded with a "require" or "do" command.