# Old .pl modules versus new .pm modules

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm a beginner in Perl and I'm trying to build in my head the best ways of structuring a Perl program. I'm proficient in Python and I'm used to the python  `from foo import bar` way of importing functions and classes from python modules. As I understood in Perl there are many ways of doing this, .pm and .pl modules, EXPORTs and @ISAs, use and require, etc. and it is not easy for a beginner to get a clear idea of which are the differences, advantages and drawbacks of each (even after reading Beginning Perl and Intermediate Perl).

The problem stated, my current question is related to a sentence from [`perldoc perlmod`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html):

> Perl module files have the
>   extension .pm. The `use` operator
>   assumes this so you don't have to
>   spell out "Module.pm" in quotes. This
>   also helps to differentiate new
>   modules from old .pl and .ph files.

Which are the differences between *old* .pl way of preparing modules and the *new* .pm way?

Are they really the *old* and the *modern* way? (I assume they are because Perlmod says that but I would like to get some input about this).

Comment: Duplicate : [What is the Difference between .pm(perl module) and .pl(perl script) file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402821/what-is-the-difference-between-pmperl-module-and-plperl-script-file)

Comment: @Zaid: no, the question you link to asks what/why is the difference between plain scripts and the modules. Here is the question about the difference between old-style `require`-ed and new-style `use`-ed modules.

Comment: @Dummy, Yes correct. I already knew about the other SO question before writing mine. @Everybody: Thanks for your time, very helpful. Regretfully I can select only one question as the best.

Comment: @Zaid: looks like you have enough reputation to submit close votes now -- since you commented that this is a dupe, you should submit a vote as such. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which are the differences between old .pl way of preparing modules and the new .pm way?

You can find few old modules inside the Perl's own standard library (pointed to by `@INC`, the paths can be seen in `perl -V` output).

In older times, there were no packages. One was doing e.g. `require "open2.pl";` which is analogous to essentially including the content of file as it is in the calling script. All functions declared, all global variables were becoming part of the script's context. Or in other words: polluting your context. Including several files might have lead to all possible conflicts.

New modules use [`package`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) keyword to define their own context and name of the namespace. When [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html)-ed by a script, new modules have possibility to not import/add anything to the immediate context of the script thus prevent namespace pollution and potential conflicts.

`@EXPORT`/`@EXPORT_OK` lists are used by standard utility module `Exporter` which helps to import the module functions into the calling context: so that one doesn't have to write all the time full name of the functions. The lists are generally customized by the module depending on the parameter list passed to the `use` like in `use POSIX qw/:errno_h/;`. See [`perldoc Exporter`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) for more details.

[`@ISA`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html#Inheritance) is a Perl's inheritance mechanism. It tells Perl that if it can't find a function inside of the current package, to scan for the function inside all the packages mentioned in the `@ISA`. Simple modules often have there only the `Exporter` mentioned to use its `import()` method (what is also well described in the same `perldoc Exporter`).

Answer (score 10):

The `use` function and `.pm`-type modules were introduced in Perl 5, released 16 years ago next month.  The "old .pl and .ph files" perlmod is referring to were used with Perl 4 (and earlier).  At this point, they're only interesting to computer historians.  For your purposes, just forget about `.pl` libraries.

Comment: To be specific, Perl 5's Sweet Sixteen will be on 17-Oct-2010.  (Perl itself will be 23 years old in December.)

Answer (score 3):

Reusing code by creating .pl files (the "pl" actually stands for "Perl library") was the way that it was done back in Perl 4 - before we had the 'package' keyword and the 'use' statement.

It's a nasty old way of doing things. If you're coming across documentation that recommends it then that's a strong indication that you should ignore that documentation as it's either really old or written by someone who hasn't kept up to date with Perl development for over fifteen years.

For some examples of the different ways of building Perl modules in the modern way, see [my answer to Perl Module Method Calls: Can't call method “X” on an undefined value at ${SOMEFILE} line ${SOMELINE}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597605/perl-module-method-calls-cant-call-method-x-on-an-undefined-value-at-somefi/3598353#3598353)

Comment: So you are suggesting that the 5.12.2 team are not "p to date with Perl development" :-)   Seriously it is rather old info. Anyone who new about Perl4 has prob converted to Perl 5 by now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know nothing about .pl rather modules rather than they did exist some time ago, nobody seems to use them nowadays so you proably shouldn't use them either.

Stick to pm modules, ignore @ISA right now, that's for OOP. Export isn't that important either, because you can always call your methods fully quallified.

So rather than writing this:

file: MyPkg.pm

```
package MyPkg;
@EXPORT = qw(func1 func2);

sub func1 { ... };
sub func2 { ... };
```

file: main.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use MyPkg;

&func1();
```

you should, for the beginning, write that:

file: MyPkg.pm

```
package MyPkg;

sub func1 { ... };
sub func2 { ... };
```

file: main.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use MyPkg;

&MyPkg::func1();
```

And later when you see which methods should really be exported you can do that without having to change your exisiting code.

The use loades your module and call import, which would make any EXPORTed subs avalable in your current package. In the seconds example a require would do, which doesn't call import, but I tend to always use 'use'.

Comment: Your first version of MyPkg won't work as you say without loading Exporter.

Comment: "Non OO" modules generally use ISA to define an import routine via Exporter.  To misquote Orwell, "all modules are OO, some are more OO than others".

Comment: justintime: This is also "old way". Modern is "use Exporter 'import';". It is available from 5.8.3, which is also old, and can be used even on older Perls with Exporter,pm upgrade from CPAN.