# What is the difference between library files and modules?

Tags: perl

What is the difference between library files and modules in Perl?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's all Perl code to `perl`. All distinctions are purely idiomatic.

Perl code meant for inclusion that uses a `package` directive:

- Called "module".
- Usually has the extension `.pm`. Must have this extension for `use` to find them.
- Should always be loaded with [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html), possibly via [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html).

  - Must therefore return a true value.
- More modular, better supported by CPAN.

Perl code meant for inclusion that doesn't use a `package` directive:

- Called "library". (At least historically. These days, "library" might also be used to refer to a module or distribution.)
- Usually has the extension `.pl`.
- Should always be loaded with [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html).
- Pollutes the caller's namespace.
- Usually indicative of a substandard design. *Avoid these!*

Perl code meant for direct execution by interpreter:

- Called "script".
- Usually has the extension `.pl`, or none at all.
- Will probably start with a shebang (`#!`) line so they can be started without specifying `perl`.

Answer (score 7):

Library files (I'm assuming you mean `require 'foo.pl'` stuff here) are an obsolete (pre-Perl 5) form of external module.  For the most part, you shouldn't need to care any more, although there *are* still some Perl 4 installations around and therefore still some Perl code that remains backward compatible with them (and there's some code that's simply never been updated and still loads `getcwd.pl` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. They are both files that contain Perl code. Here are some of the possible circumstantial differences, though.

1. A perl executable is more likely to have a `#!/bin/perl` shbang.
2. Old `.pl` Perl *libraries* (hence the 'p' + 'l') are more likely to expect to be *required* than `.pm` modules.
3. Perl 5 style (`.pm`) modules are more likely to use `Exporter` -- although *even newer* module eschew exporting anything.

Comment: A module always defines a package (or else it's not a module). a `.pl` library usually doesn't.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by #2. `.pm` (i.e. files a `package` directive) should always be loaded with [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html), possibly via [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html). `.pl` (i.e. files without a `package` directive) should always be loaded with [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html).

Comment: @ikegami, 1) If someone gave you a .pm file, would you expect to need to require (or even `do`) it? Or is it more of a question if you had a .pl file. 2) Package directive doesn't enter into it when talking about the file types, but out of the two--I'd more likely expect that a .pm file defines a package than a .pl file. So it's also in the vein of a difference of practice in creating the two types of files. Again, suggested practice is different from *de facto*--or characteristic--practice--in my experience with .pl files--I have never seen somebody `do` them--advisability not withstanding.

Comment: If someone gave me a .pm file, I would expect it to have a `package` directive, and thus, I would expect to be able to load it using `require`. I too would also more likely expect that a .pm file defines a package than a .pl file, which is why I said .pm should always be loaded with `require`, and why I said .pl should never be loaded using `require`.