# Perl problem 'require' the same file

Tags: perl

I have a shared module in perl. The main program needs two files, first, a shared file (let's call it 'X'), and, second, a 'package' file. File 'X' is also included in the 'package' file using 'require'. When I compile this program it gives me the following error:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::trim called at testing.pl line 8.
```

My understanding is that perl couldn't find the trim() module. If I don't include the package file, then this will run without any problem.

Can anyone shed light on this problem?

These are my codes:

Main program: testing.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use postgres;

require "shared.pl";

trim("als");
```

Package File: postgres.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package postgres;

use strict;
use DBI;

require "shared.pl";

1;
```

shared file: shared.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# =============
# shared module 
# =============

use strict;

sub trim($)
{
}

1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `require` will only load a file one time. In this case, that one time is from the file `postgres.pm`, in the `postgres` package. So the `trim` subroutine gets defined in the `postgres` namespace as `&postgres::trim`.

One workaround would be to use the fully qualified subroutine name in the `testing.pl` file:

```
postgres::trim("als");       # not trim("als")
```

Another workaround is to hack the [`%INC`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#INC) table (the variable that keeps track of what modules/files have already been `use`'d and `require`'d) so you can reload `shared.pl` into the main package:

```
use postgres;

delete $INC{"shared.pl"};
require "shared.pl";
```

A third workaround would be to export the `trim` function from the `postgres` package to the main package. The docs for the [`Exporter`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Exporter) module are a good introduction to why and how this is done.

```
# in postgres.pm
*main::trim = *trim;

# or in testing.pl
*trim = *postgres::trim;
trim("als");
```

Comment: `delete $INC{"shared.pl"};` waaaa? nooo!

Answer (score 5):

If the module doesn't use `package`, you want [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) instead of [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html). See [What is the difference between library files and modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376006/what-is-the-difference-between-library-files-and-modules).

```
do "shared.pl" or die $@;
```

You really should create a proper module, one with a `package` statement.

```
package Shared;

use strict;
use warnings;

our @EXPORT = qw( trim );
use Exporter qw( import );

sub trim { ... }

1;
```

Name the file `Shared.pm` and load it using `use Shared;`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Obviously, I still have a lot to learn about how to properly code in perl.