# Perl CPAN dictionary

Tags: perl, cpan

In the Perl world there is a great thing called [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/). It is a big storage for open source Perl libraries.

I use modules from CPAN and I have released [several distributions myself](https://metacpan.org/author/BESSARABV).

I use CPAN, but there is one essential thing that I don't understand. I don't know what words are used for the different things on CPAN. In the beginning of this post I have used the words `libraries`, `modules`, `distributions`, but I'm not sure that I have used them correctly.

Can you please explain what each of this words means in case of CPAN (if they can be used in the scope of CPAN):

- module
- package
- release
- distribution
- library

Comment: Partial answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6376006/1030675

Comment: @choroba, In that answer, I wasn't trying to define terms. I used the OP's definition of library, which is rarely what is meant by library. Still, it's probably great related reading.

Answer (score 15):

All of these terms have "flexible" definitions, even in a Perl context. In a Perl context, they most commonly mean the following:

- module

  A file providing functions to be called by other files or a class to be used by other files.

  It will have the `.pm` extension. It will have a `package` directive. It will usually be loaded using `use`. etc

  Example: XML/LibXML.pm
- package

  A [directive](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) that instructs Perl into which namespace to place symbols. It's also used as a synonym for "namespace".

  Example: XML::LibXML
- distribution

  A collection of modules including an installer. What is found on CPAN.

  Example: XML-LibXML
- library

  Not part of Perl jargon, except perhaps when indicating a distribution provides an interface to a C library. In C, it refers to a collection of functions and symbols which can be accessed by other objects and executables.

  Example: libxml2
- release

  A specific version of something.

  Example: XML-LibXML-2.0104.tar.gz

Comment: Thank you! So If I undestand you correctly this is how to call things: "There is a distribution Plack that has several modules including Plack::Builder module. The latest release of Plack is 1.0029"

Comment: distributions don't have to have modules; some have just scripts, or some could have just data, I suppose.  And some exist just to make it easy to install multiple other distributions (their "dependencies").

Comment: True, though CPAN doesn't handle distributions without module very well. (That's why scripts are released as pseudo-modules in the App:: namespace.)