# perl "do" works "require" doesn't: Undefined subroutine

Tags: perl

As I have been refactoring some of my code from what someone called "perl 4 coding style" to use `package`s, I have a question on something I still don't quite fully understand. I know that `use` includes a file at compile time, and `require` at runtime (among other differences), both being run as if in the `BEGIN` section. I know that `do` is kind of like `eval` (with some differences).

I have a script (B) that can be run on its own, and I am calling it from another script (C) as a `require`. *Script B* calls a `require` on a .pm file (A) which has just two subs (one to set a variable, and another to return it) and a variable declared as `our` (I'm guessing `my` would achieve the same here though). This .pm is *not* encapsulated with `package` (hence the situation). If I run *script B*, it works without a hitch. If I `require` *script B* from *script C* (which also has a `require` for a `package`'d .pm that `require`s A.pm, and uses the accessor func), I get:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::func_in_A called at script_B
```

However, if I `do` *A.pm* in *script_B* everything works as expected.

As I was typing up the question, I think I realize what is happening, but let me ask anyway just to make sure.

Is this as a result of the fact that `require` keeps track of the files it has loaded (while `do` does not), such that it loads a file exactly once, despite the fact that that once was in the package's namespace, and hence the symbols will not be brought into MAIN when doing a `require` there? If not, then what am I missing here?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question -- hobbs already has -- but you might be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6379109/589924)

Comment: ah interesting, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I think that your diagnosis is right. Since A.pm lacks a `package` statement, subs within it will be defined under whatever package was active when the file was evaluated. Since `do` has no protection against double-evaluation, A's subs up in two different packages. Since `require` does, they end up in one package, and which package depends on who loads A first.

Solution: don't use `require` (and certainly not `use`) on files without `package` statements :)

Comment: great! Thanks for the input! I'm going to wait and see if anyone else has something to add to that.

Comment: It seems I never accepted this as the answer back when I asked it. Sorry about that!

Comment: @insaner ha, no problem at all :)