# The "wrong" package specification is required to call a subroutine

Tags: perl, class, oop

I would like to ask you for advice on writing a Perl module. We have three files.

(1) main.pl : uses `my_function()`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use MyClass;
require "./subroutines.pl";

my $instance = MyClass->new({});
$instance->my_method("a");

MyClass::my_function("b"); # This works.
my_function("c"); # Undefined subroutine &main::my_function called

exit;
```

(2) MyClass.pm : defines MyClass class. `my_method()` uses `my_function()` which is defined in "subroutines.pl".

```
package MyClass;
use strict;
use warnings;
require "./subroutines.pl";

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = shift;
  return bless $self, $class;
}

sub my_method{
  my $self = shift;
  my $text = shift;
  my_function($text);
}

1;
```

(3) subroutines.pl : defines `my_function()`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub my_function {
  print "[$_[0]] My function is working!\n";
}

1;
```

The problem is that `my_function()` is not working in main.pl, even though the source code has `require "./subroutines.pl"`, while `MyClass::my_function()` works.

```
[a] My function is working!
[b] My function is working!
Undefined subroutine &main::my_function called at main.pl line 11.
```

Because `my_function()` is useful for me, I want to use it in both main.pl and MyClass.pm, but the subroutine is so general that it is quite strange to define it as a method in MyClass.pm. But it is also strange (to me) that we have to write `MyClass::` before `my_function()`, because the subroutine does not depend on `MyClass`.

My question is: **is it possible to modify the above codes so that `my_function()` works in main.pl without adding `MyClass::` before the function call?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` only executes a given file once, so you would need `do`, but that would created two copies of the subroutine. Use a proper module instead, and use Exporter to export the symbol.

`Subroutines.pm`:

```
package Subroutines;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw( import );
our @EXPORT = qw( my_function );

sub my_function {
  print "[$_[0]] My function is working!\n";
}

1;
```

and

```
use Subroutines;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that *.pm was only for classes.

Comment: It's for modules, whether they classes or not. I discussed the Perl-related file types [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376006/what-is-the-difference-between-library-files-and-modules/6379109#6379109)

Comment: Oops, the `package` directive was missing. Added.