# What does 'Cwd' and 'qw' mean in perl?

Tags: perl

In perl, we import/use module we `use Cwd;`
`qw` as representation of list/array.

But, I see in some code it's mentioned as below.

```
use Cwd qw(realpath cwd);
realpath( $0 ) =~ /(.+)\/[^\/]+$/;
require "$1/some_file.pl"
```

What does this mean ? Can you please help me to understand ?

Comment: The [documentation of `use`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) is a good starting point

Comment: `use MODULE LIST` loads the MODULE and imports its symbols given in LIST into the current package. So `use Cwd 'getcwd'` will import `getcwd` into the current package. If you did only do `use Cwd`, the symbol `getcwd` would not be directly available, and you would need to write `Cwd::getcwd()` to call the function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`qw/STRING/` is the quote-word [quote-like operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

```perl
qw(realpath cwd)
```

is equivalent to

```perl
split(' ', q(realpath cwd))
```

and thus to

```perl
'realpath', 'cwd'
```

So,

```perl
use Cwd qw(realpath cwd);
```

is equivalent to

```perl
use Cwd 'realpath', 'cwd';
```

---

According to [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html),

```perl
use Module LIST;
```

is equivalent to

```perl
BEGIN {
   require Module;
   Module->import(LIST);
}
```

so

```perl
use Cwd 'realpath', 'cwd';
```

is equivalent to

```perl
BEGIN {
   require Cwd;
   Cwd->import('realpath', 'cwd');
}
```

---

So what does `import` do? Well, that's entirely up to the module. It's common for modules to export the listed symbols into the caller's namespace. Cwd is no exception.

So, the following loads Cwd (if it's not already), and imports the functions `realpath` and `cwd` from it.

```perl
use Cwd qw(realpath cwd);
```

---

Finally,

`$0`, documented in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), is the name of the script being executed.

`realpath($0)` is an absolute path to the script being executed, with symlinks resolved.

The regex match is used to extract everything up to the last `/`, i.e. the directory name in which the script is located.

Finally, [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) executes the specified file. (Although `require` is not the [correct tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379109/589924) for this.)

A simpler version of your code:

```perl
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
require("$RealBin/some_file.pl");
```