# perlcritic: "require" statement with library name as string Use a bareword instead

Tags: perl, perl-critic

Perlcritic complains about the following line of code:

`require "bin/menu.pl";`

"require" statement with library name as string Use a bareword instead.

However if I change it to a bare word:

`require bin/menu.pl`

I get an illegal division by zero error.

To reproduce just run perlcritic on any perl script that 'requires' another perl script.

The docs for require suggest using a string:
https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require
Is this a bug in perlcritic?

Comment: As a bare word it's wrong if it has Perl syntax in it like `/`.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between library files and modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379109/589924)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should ignore Perl::Critic. It's perfectly fine to load a library with `require` like you are doing. It's not popular anymore, but that is the original idea of `require`. Tell Perl::Critic to ignore that line:

```
require 'some/path/some_library.pl'; ## nocritic
```

Don't use Perl::Critic to tell you what to do. Use it as a tool to look at things that might need attention, then make a decision based on the context of your task.

As people have noted, require will only execute the code the first time around. If that's what you want (and it probably is because that's been working up to now), leave the code as is.

Some people have suggested turning this into a module, in which case you probably just end up exporting all the subroutines anyway. You end up in the same place with extra steps. That might be fine when you're looking for something to do and can't find anything more pressing.

---

@ikegami's point is in general correct, and my answer is only appropriate in the situation presented. `require` tracks that files it has already processed so it does not reprocess it again. If the code in the library defines its own namespace, anything in the program can access the subs (or whatever) it defines through that namespace.

If it does not define a namespace, whatever it does ends up in whatever the default namespace was when it was executed. That can pollute that namespace and you might not be able to know where those definitions ended up. Generally, small programs use `main::` and never leave it, and everything ends up in `main::` so it all works out.

If the library executed code when required (so, stuff outside of sub definitions), you have to decide if you need that to happen multiple times. That would be a weird situation and probably raises eyebrows, but `do` would handle that.

But, more likely, people want those things to happen only once, so `require` handles that. Say that you set a global variable in this library, but go on to modify it elsewhere in the program. Bad practice, but that's how the world is. If you run the library code again, your variable is silently reset.

If you were starting fresh, do what @ikegami says. If you are supporting code that been running fine, just let it do its thing even if it is wrong. Even known bugs are sometimes left better undisturbed until you have the proper amount of time to ensure the fix isn't worse. It always seems like it should work if you just make this one change, and then it ends up all broken in different ways that nobody expects. I've rescued many situations where someone decided to change something working because Perl::Critic told them to, and now they had 99 problems. (Heh, don't set default regex flags!)

At some point you might have time to clean up that stuff, but more likely there is other work that should take up your time. I should have made that more clear in my original answer.

Comment: Re "*Don't use Perl::Critic to tell you what to do.*", True, except if found an actual bug here. /// Re "*It's perfectly fine to load a library with require like you are doing.*", No, it's not. The `require` could do absolutely nothing instead of importing the contents of the file. `require` is the wrong tool for old-style "libraries". `require` should only use for modules, which is to say files with a `package`. `do` should be used in this situation.

Comment: @ikegami I think 'require' runs some extra checks over 'do' but there is no difference otherwise. If you have an example of how using require on a pl file is a bug that would be helpful. I think this is a bug in perl-critic as require supports loading pl files in a string.

Comment: Sorry, meant to get back to this to explain why @ikegami is right in general. which is almost always true even if you don't see it right away. Then it got too long for a comment.

Comment: @turlte The problem occurs when you require the same "library" twice.

Comment: @ikegami I created two test files in my /tmp/test that behave like the old perl program. one called main.pl and one called lib.pl, I have main.pl calling require on lib.pl twice to see if I can get a bug, but no bug.  https://pastebin.com/zAW5J4jZ  https://pastebin.com/b1xFa1aq

Comment: Makes no sense for one namespace to load the same module twice. What makes sense if having two namespaces that both use the same module.  That's what fails with `require` when using a `library`. Short test: `package Foo; require("lib.pl"); dostuff(); package Bar; require("lib.pl"); dostuff();`. (It's all in one file here, but normally it's in different files.) `do` is for libraries from 25 years ago, `require` is for modules.

Comment: @ikegami thank you for sticking with me and for the example of when using require on a .pl  would be a bug. In the case of this particular project the require is only ever used from within another script .pl file.

Comment: Re "*If you are supporting code that been running fine, just let it do its thing even if it is wrong.*", It's not. That's why they came here. That's why you suggested changing the code. You suggested changing it to silence perlcritic. But the error could be fixed just as easily. No reason not to.

Comment: The program was running fine, I am a new maintainer for an old project and was just running perl critic. There are over a dozen script .pl files that just run in the main namspace, and my understanding is using require instead of do will prevent the same lib from being loaded twice, where as do will not.

Answer (score 3):

Perl critic tells you the canonical way is to use the bareword form of [require](https://perldoc.pl/require):

```
require Some::Module;
```

Requiring a script is not a good idea (because it doesn't run it every time it's required, but might run it more than once if the path is not the same; also, it's unclear what namespace the required script pollutes). You should require modules (or, even better, [use](https://perldoc.pl/use) them).

A bareword can't contain a slash. It's therefore interpreted as the division operator, and as you aren't using [strict](https://perldoc.pl/strict), it interprets the barewords `bin`, `menu`, and `pl` as strings. As they don't start with digits, their value in numeric context (which `/` enforces) is 0.

```bash
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e 'lib/menu.pl'
(('lib' / 'menu') . 'pl');
-e syntax OK
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its a pretty large old project, not of my design, it has a big mix of script files and modules, and I can't rename files. The require for a .pl file has to stay for the time being. I am still unclear what the hazard or bug is with using require "bin/script.pl',. I have otherwise fixed all other perlcritic complaints.

Comment: @turtle: The hazard is the script won't run where you expect it to, because it has already run when required somewhere else. Another problem might be running it several times, importing the subs into different namespaces. Requiring scripts was a thing in the 90s when `use` didn't exist yet.

Answer (score 2):

**If `bin/menu.pl` has a package statement**

Say the package statement is `package My::Menu;`.

- Make sure it ends with a true value (e.g. has `1;` at the end).
- Rename the file to `My/Menu.pm`.
- Use `use My::Menu;`.

---

**If `bin/menu.pl` doesn't have package statement**

It's not a module, so don't load it like one.

- Make sure it ends with a true value (e.g. has `1;` at the end).
- Use `do( "bin/menu.pl" ) or die( $@ // $! );`.

Consider converting it to a module. We haven't been constrained to this poor style of programming for about 25 years.

---

See [What is the difference between library files and modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379109/589924)