# Can you have a Perl class without .pm tag?

Tags: perl, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Perl, what is the difference between a .pm (Perl module) and .pl (Perl script) file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402821/in-perl-what-is-the-difference-between-a-pm-perl-module-and-pl-perl-script)

I'm trying to set up a Perl class on my host's server (iPage).  But their config only recognizes Perl files with the .cgi or the .pl file tags.  Is it possible to set up a Perl class without using the .pm tag?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3405551/390913

Answer (score 7):

You can't use the `use Class::Name;` syntax; you'll have to do `require 'path/to/filename.pl';` instead.  Other than that, it doesn't matter; the class name is equal to the name in the `package` statement, not the filename.

But what do you mean "their config only recognizes..."?  If you have any way to get a file named `.pm` onto the server, you don't need their config to "recognize" it - it just needs to be where your Perl code (presumably in `.cgi` or `.pl` files) can find it.

Comment: I'm gonna give it a try.  Thanks Mark.  I appreciate it.