# Can't locate *.pm in INC

Tags: perl

I am a newbie to `Perl`. Sorry for my stupid question.

I have some code like this:

```
bintest.pl
subfolder/sample.pl
```

And in the `sample.pl`, some is defined like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use lib '.';
use lib '..';
use bintest qw(:DEFAULT 
    $client_routine
    );
```

However, when I use `perl sample.pl` in the `subfolder`, I got this error:

```
Can't locate bintest.pm in @INC (@INC contains: .. . /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at sample.pl line 6.
```

Am I missed anything? Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: `bintest.pl` != `bintest.pm`

Comment: @Biffen, sorry.. but how can I get a bintest.pm from bintest.pl..? thank you!

Comment: You can't just ‘get’ a Perl module from a Perl script. May I suggest you [read up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_module) on [Perl modules/packages](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html)?

Answer (score 8):

[use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) does something very specific:

> It is exactly equivalent to
>
> ```
> BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }
> ```

[require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) also does something very specific:

> If EXPR is a bareword, the require assumes a ".pm" extension and replaces "::" with "/" in the filename for you, to make it easy to load standard modules.

So, when you say

> ```
> use bintest ( .. );
> ```

`perl` first tries to locate `bintest.pm` in one of the directories in `@INC` (which now also contains `.` and `..` thanks to your `use lib` statements).

It can't find it, because what you have is `bintest.pl`.

You could `require '../bintest.pl'`, and then invoke `bintest->import( ... )` yourself in a `BEGIN` block, but, I am assuming you don't want to go there.

I will recommend that you use a different directory structure:

- `$project_root/bin`: Your scripts live here
- `$project_root/lib`: Your `.pm` files live here

Put in `$project_root/lib/My/Bintest.pm` the following file

```
package My::Bintest;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw( import );

1;
__END__
```

Then, from your script in `$project_root/bin/script.pl`, you can do:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib "$RealBin/../lib";
use My::Bintest qw( ... );
```

Comment: @ikegami Ooops! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have two Perl **programs** called `bintest.pl` and `sample.pl`. You have no Perl **modules**. The function [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) is used to load Perl modules. When `use` converts the module name it is given to a filename to search for, one of the things it does is to append ".pm" to the name.

So given that you have a program (`bintest.pl`) and not a module (which would be called `bintest.pm`), it's not at all surprising that `use` can't find it.

The real question is, of course, what can you do to fix this problem? And that's hard to answer without a lot more information. It's possible that `bintest` should be a module and that someone has just given it the wrong name - in which case just renaming it would work. It's possible that it is an old-style Perl library - in which case loading it with `require` rather than `use` might well work. But it's equally possible that it's really a program and you shouldn't be trying to use it in this way.

With knowing more about the code (where it comes from, how it is documented, what it looks like) it is impossible to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Please see "[In Perl, what is the difference between a .pm (Perl module) and .pl (Perl script) file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402821/in-perl-what-is-the-difference-between-a-pm-perl-module-and-pl-perl-script)"